# Cannot GET /resources/cards

Tags: node.js, file, express, static, serve

I'm having issues trying to serve static files with expressJS.
I want to serve files from a folder, using virtual route.

My app architecture looks like this

```
├── app
|   ├── assets
|       └── data
|           └── img
|               └── cards
|                   └── * (un bunch of image files)
|   └── index.js
|   └── server.js
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
```

My index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();


//Serving images
app.use('resources/cards', express.static(path.join('assets/data/img/cards')));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.send('Hello World');
});

module.exports = app;
```

My server.js

```js
const app = require('./index');
const config = require('./config');
//Mysql connection
const mysql = require('mysql');



app.listen(config.express.port, function() {
    console.log(`Running on ${config.express.ip}:${config.express.port}`);
});


const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.mysql.host,
    user: config.mysql.username,
    password: config.mysql.password,
    port: config.mysql.port,
    database: config.mysql.database,
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`The solution is ${rows[0].solution}`);
});

//connection.end();
```

I want to access my images through localhost:3000/resources/cards/image.png, for example, but still getting this `Cannot GET /resources/cards`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by specifying the [mount path](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use) as absolute and add `__dirname` to the `path.join(...)`:

```
app.use('/resources/cards', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets/data/img/cards')));
```

Comment: Still getting ```Cannot GET /resources/cards``` , I have this console error. I don't think it's helping but :
```Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.```

Comment: that's not related to this. The browser makes an extra request to `/favicon.ico` with each request (you can make a request to `http://localhost:3000/` and see you'll also have another request to `/favicon.ico`)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explaination ! I looking for answers in Express documentation but I don't see what i'm doing wrong...
Could my app architecture be related to this ?

Comment: It worked ! I didn't see but I typed ```path.join(__dirname + '/assets/data/img/cards')``` instead of ```path.join(__dirname, 'assets/data/img/cards')```

Thank you a lot !